# How is modifying a class in `reopenClass` different than extending a class with `extend`?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm playing with the fixture adapter in Ember.js.

This:

```
let cars = DS.Model.extend({
  make: attr('string'),
  model: attr('string'),
  year: attr('string'),
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      model: 'foo',
      make: 'bar',
      year: '2001'
    }
  ]
});
```

Throws "unable to find fixtures"

Whereas this:

```
let cars = DS.Model.extend({
  make: attr('string'),
  model: attr('string'),
  year: attr('string'),
});

cars.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: 1,
      model: 'foo',
      make: 'bar',
      year: '2001'
    }
  ]
});
```

Works great. I would expect them to be the same, though, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

With `reopenClass` you put something on the class instead of the instance.

So if you have a class, and do a `reopen` and a `reopenClass`:

```
const MyClass = Ember.Object.extend({
  foo: 'foo'
})`;
myClass.reopen({
  bar: 'bar'
});
myClass.reopenClass({
  baz: 'baz'
});
```

and then you create an instance

```
const myInstance = MyClass.create({});
```

Then you can access `foo` and `bar` on the instance:

```
myInstance.get('foo'); // foo
myInstance.get('bar'); // bar
```

but `baz on the class itself:

```
myClass.get('baz'); // baz
```

Comment: To clarify: `reopenClass` is basically used for specifying static attributes of classes in Ember. `extend` and `reopen` are called on classes to define or overwrite instance attributes. Would you say that's a fitting description?

Comment: Correct for `reopenClass`. The difference between `extend` and `reopen` is, that `extend` creates a *new* class, and `reopen` changes an existing class. But yeah, both is for instance attributes/functions.